# how to merge video clips using avfoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I have successfully merge the video clips to a single video but I am having a problem in the final merged video, the final video shows a white frame after the end of every video clip. I have tried a lot to remove this but couldn't find success. Please review my code below.

```
func merge(arrayVideos:[AVAsset], completion:@escaping (_ exporter: AVAssetExportSession) -> ()) -> Void {

    let mainComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionVideoTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
    let soundtrackTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    var time:Double = 0.0

    for (index, videoAsset) in arrayVideos.enumerated() {
        let atTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale: 1)
        try! compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: atTime)
        try! soundtrackTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: atTime)
        time += videoAsset.duration.seconds
    }

    let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "merge.mp4")
    print("final URL:\(outputFileURL)")
    let fileManager = FileManager()

    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(at: outputFileURL)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.domain)")
    }

    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mainComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter?.outputURL = outputFileURL
    exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter?.exportAsynchronously {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(exporter!)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `Double` to track the insertion time, this can result in gaps due to rounding errors. And don't use a `preferredTimescale` of 1 when converting seconds, this will effectively round everything to whole seconds (1000 would be a more common timescale for this).

Instead to track the insertion time use a `CMTime` initialized to `kCMTimeZero`, and use `CMTimeAdd` to advance it.

And one more thing: Video and audio tracks can have different durations, particularly when recorded. So to keep things in sync, you may want to use `CMTimeRangeGetIntersection` to get the common time range of audio and video in the asset, and then use result to for insertion in the composition.